# How to determine a probability that 100% of confidence intervals from a bootstrap contain the true mean

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, bootstrap

Say I take 500 bootstraps of a population and calculate 95% confidence intervals (CIs) for each sample. I would expect that 95% of the bootstrap sample CIs to contain the true population mean. However, I'm then asked what the probability is of 100% of the bootstrap sample CIs contain the true population mean.

I though that a simple binomial would work, but it's giving me an answer I don't believe:

(500 choose 500) ((.95)^500)*((.05)^0)

Comment: *If* the bootstrap samples have exactly the desired coverage probability (and are independent), the correct answer is indeed $0.95^{500}$ (which should be - very roughly - about $e^{-25}$). (In practice the bootstrap coverage is often quite some distance from the nominal coverage, however.) Why do you find that result surprising? Did you think it should be smaller or larger?

Comment: It just seems wild to me that we expect 95% of the 500 samples CIs to contain the true mean, but the probability that the remaining 25, in addition, will have CIs that cover the mean is 7.27 x 10 -12.

I though it would be larger.

Comment: @glen Why is it valid to assume the bootstrap CIs act like independent Bernoulli trials with 95% chance of coverage?

Comment: @whuber I didn't anywhere claim it was; my statement was conditional on my opening (and italicized for emphasis) "*If*" -- & raised because that's the calculation in the Q. Indeed, I explicitly denied one of the assumptions right there in the comment. The other one (independence) I didn't address, because I was trying to think of a good way to discuss it briefly, but the point of the comment was to solicit what was surprising about the calculation under that Bernoulli process assumption (and in what direction), since I thought that would impact any attempt to answer the question. ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... The response seems to suggest a possible probability misconception that might need to be addressed in dealing with a more realistic calculation.

Comment: @Glen The implicit assumption I am asking about is that the CI coverages are independent, for that is essential for making the $0.95^{500}$ computation. But the heart of my concern is this: that number would seem to give the chance that all $500$ bootstrap CIs cover the *sample* mean, but wouldn't such a calculation be irrelevant to assessing whether the CIs cover the *population* mean?